# Why won't wrapper div expand when it has an absolute child div

Tags: html, parent, wrapper, expand, absolute

I have a wrapper div set to 960px and inside it, I have another div called "slider".
Slider is positioned absolutely in the middle of the screen using this code:

```
#slider {width:390px; height:100px; position:absolute; 
         margin:-100px 0 0 -200px; top:50%; left:50%; border:1px solid;}
```

I have added borders to both the wrapper and slider divs so that I can see how they are positioned on the screen however, this has revealed that the wrapper is not expanding to contain the absolute slider div.

How do I fix this so that the height of the wrapper is correct?

Comment: You should create a http://jsfiddle.net testcase to make easier people to help you. From the top of my head I'd tell you to make the wrapper position:relative and position the child margins relative to wrapper not the entire page.

Comment: Share the code for your wrapper div too. Do you have overflow:auto in wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `position:absolute;` on an element it is position outside of the document flow and does not impact on the other content.

If you can, remove `position:absolute;` and use other methods to center your slider div.  If you need the `position:absolute;` then it is not possible.

Comment: what other methods can I use to position the DIV in the centre witouht absolute positioning?

Comment: You can use several methods, `margin:auto` is a popular method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-a-div-in-a-div and http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html for more info on the details.